# Auto-Generate insert statements to store enum values to Database using Java Reflection

Tags: java, database, hibernate, enums

I am using Spring + JPA/Hibernate + Oracle in my application. I have bunch of look up tables in my database and I have enums at the data layer. I need to auto-generate sql statement to insert enum values to their respective lookup table if it doesn't already exists.

Using reflection I was able to enum values and establishing a connection to the database and inserting is not a problem. My problem is that the table name and column names are different in the database from enum class.

I am thinking of using a Map > to take care of the mapping between enum class and lookup table for the query and also put column names there as well.

Code:

```
public enum AddressType implements StringValuedEnum {
HOME("HOME", true), 
WORK("WORK", true);

private String dbCode;
private Boolean active;

private AddressType(String dbCode) {
    this.setDbCode(dbCode);
}

private AddressType(String dbCode, Boolean active){
    this.setDbCode(dbCode);
    this.setActive(active);
}

@Override
public String getDbCode() {
    return this.dbCode;
}

public void setDbCode(String dbCode) {
    this.dbCode = dbCode;
}

public Boolean getActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(Boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

}
```

Address Type in database:
      T_ADDR_TYP
         ADDR_TYP_NM
         ADDR_TYP_DESC
         ACTV_IND

Does anybody know a better way of doing this?

Comment: So, you try to generate queries using the enum values as a table name ?

Comment: Can you update with table structure also?